# How is moderator inactivity identified and handled?

Tags: discussion, moderators

My question is just for knowledge purpose and nothing more.

There are many moderators for individual Stack Exchange sites. What if a moderator goes on a long vacation, or goes somewhere from where he isn't able to access his account?

A few questions:

- How does the community detect that a moderator is idle?
- What happens if a moderator goes idle for a long period of time, or permanently?
- Is there a way for a person with a moderator account's password to sit on the moderator's seat and perform everything that was done by the moderator?
- When a moderator goes offline [RIP], what does the community do?
- If I find that a moderator is no longer available, can I ask the community to appoint me in his/her place?

Comment: So moderators are prohibited to take long vacations? I don't want to work for you :)

Comment: @juergend, No --- every human / animals should take long (long) vacations! It's a need to live healthy and happy.

Comment: There are elections for moderators and there are (normally) enough moderators that not every moderator needs to be active every single day.

Comment: OK, that's fine for them. Then what about actual question? If a moderator really goes on vacations for a couple of months then?

Comment: I think, now I should update my question then, lets say there are 11 moderators of StackOverFlow site, if 10 of them decide to go on vacations together then?

Comment: I thought [meta-tag:burninate-system] is for handling inactive moderators

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Moderators that are inactive for around 6 months are demoted by SE. There is a dashboard only visible to moderators and SE employees that shows moderator activity, and it is rather easy to see if a moderator has become inactive.

If there is an issue with coverage due to too many moderators being away, SE usually just appoints another moderator (on beta sites), starts an election or in very minor cases SE employees just keep an eye on the site themselves.

If you want to be a moderator on SO you'll have to win an election.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Mad, can you show me some proof?

Comment: @Hemang I'm a moderator on two SE sites, this is based on my own experience.

Comment: @Hemang the page Mad Scientist is referring to is covered by the moderator agreement and therefore we can't show you it.

Comment: OK, I accept! Thanks for the knowledge sharing! Happy moderating :)