# Do new moderators replace previous or they ALL are elected in addition?

Tags: support, moderators, moderator-election

My question is pretty simple though, but do new moderators elected for example in this 2015 year replace moderators who were elected in 2014 and/or earlier?

I've found in section **Users -> Moderators** all of them, but in [**April 2015 Community Moderator Election Results**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291017/april-2015-community-moderator-election-results?cb=1) there are *"...and the 3 NEW moderators are..."*.

So basically the question could be simplified to *How long moderators elected for?*

Comment: No. Newly-elected Moderators are added to the existing group. With full Moderators, there is no time-limit. They are President for Life. Sort of.

Comment: @BillWoodger, ah, okay, because I was afraid that 3 guys gonna maintain the web-site 24/7...That's better.

Comment: The "all of them" link is all the currently-active Moderators. From time-to-time one is asked to return to Krypton, but generally they stay around a while. There are also a number of Community-something (sorry about that...) Stack Exchange employeers who have Moderator powers.

Comment: but they are not displayed in any of lists, right?

Comment: There may be a sepate list. They still have "diamonds" after their username. So any "diamond" you see who is not in the Moderator group is a Stack Exchange employee with Moderator powers. Someone who knows this better than I will probably post an answer for you, but rest assured, there are many people working to keep things running smoothly.

Comment: Until they get tired with our BS.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As shown on the [moderators](https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators) list, the new members are added to the group.  In this case, in 2015, one moderator [decided to step down](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291017/april-2015-community-moderator-election-results?cb=1) and was removed.

I also point you to the accepted answer and discussion on [Should Community Moderators be “elected for life”, or have terms?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/984/should-community-moderators-be-elected-for-life-or-have-terms) (on MSE). It states, in part, that *replacing* moderators instead of accumulating them would have the following impacts:

> You would be effectively kicking out experienced moderators.
>
> It would also mean that the moderating 'team' is split once a year. Which is also undesirable.
>
> Moderating is pretty much the same person to person. Someone who is competent will not be too different from someone else who is competent. It's not like you can have different policies for which users can vote. The job is simply to enforce the terms and conditions of the site and some maintenance/tidying up.
>
> Although Stack Overflow is meant to be community driven I am not sure on the idea on them worrying about community approval. Sometimes, not often though, it may be their job to be unpopular (say, closing a popular but wildly off-topic question).

Related: [Should Stack Overflow moderators have a “standard of duty”?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287878/should-stack-overflow-moderators-have-a-standard-of-duty)