# November 2015 Stack Overflow Community Moderator Election RESULTS

Tags: discussion, moderator-election, moderator-resignation

Stack Overflow's [November 2015 moderator election](//stackoverflow.com/election/7) has come to a close, the robots have [transferred many single votes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77541/how-are-moderator-election-votes-counted-in-plain-english) to tally up the results, and the 3 new moderators are:

[image: josilber] [image: Ed Cottrell] [image: Madara Uchiha]

They'll be joining [the existing crew](//stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly — please thank them for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](//stackoverflow.com/election/7), or [view a summary report online](https://www.opavote.com/results/6186395068530688/0).

A big thanks to everyone for participating, both those of you who volunteered to run and all those who asked questions, left feedback, and most of all **voted!** As those of us in the U.S. of A prepare to celebrate our yearly holiday of Thanksgiving, I'm reminded yet again of how fortunate we all are to be a part of such an enthusiastic, supportive community here on Stack Overflow.

---

And while we're giving thanks, I'd like to wish a fond farewell and copious gratitude to three veteran moderators who are stepping down this fall:

- **[casperOne](https://stackoverflow.com/users/50776/casperone)**  has served as a moderator since the *last* fall election in 2011
- **[Gordon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/208809/gordon)** has served since 2013
- **[Jeremy Banks](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1114/jeremy-banks)** has served since this spring

These fine people have each done a lot for Stack Overflow over the years, as moderators and as trusted members of the community - please join me in thanking them for their service and wishing them all the best in their next adventure.

## Update:

Our beloved mod [0x7fffffff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/716216/0x7fffffff) is stepping down, runners-up [Undo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1849664/undo) and [TheLostMind](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2193767/thelostmind) have agreed to take his place and help out with the workload.

[image: Undo] [image: TheLostMind]

Please welcome them to the team!

Comment: Congrats EdCottrell, MadaraUchiha, and josilber!

Comment: Thanks to all the 3 great mods who are stepping down. You've all done a great job moderating the site. Welcome to the *Normal users' club*

Comment: Thank you casperOne, Gordon, and Jeremy!

Comment: I haven't had much experience with the other 2, but Gordon, thank you for your time (as well as the other two). Enjoy retirement, which I assume is a 70 hour work week. :D

Comment: Congrats EdCottrell, MadaraUchiha and josilber

Comment: Interesting to see the [voter turnouts](http://stackoverflow.com/election?cb=1)!

Comment: The winners have 76k, 27k, and 20k reputation. I think the candidate score system has been very successful at limiting reputation bias in voting.

Comment: Very happy to see all three new mods were among the four or so I most wanted. Congrats! And thank you everyone else for giving a noble effort and allowing a better choice.

Comment: Ah, wow -- I'm really excited to have been elected! Thanks so much for all the positive messages during the election itself, and congrats to Ed and Madara as well. Thanks to casperOne, Gordon, and Jeremy Banks for their great service!

Comment: Gongrats! Good luck on moderating and keeping the forum clean!

Comment: Thank you, everyone - it's a real honor to be trusted by the community in this way. And congratulations to John and Madara, as well; I'm looking forward to working with you both!

Comment: One out of three ain't bad (not sayin' who I voted for :).  Congrats, suckers.  Now grab your mop and your bucket, there's a whole ton of vomit that needs swabbing.

Comment: first time, my first choice wins, thanks Ed, do not forget us

Comment: Congrats to the new moderators.

Comment: Well deserved! Congrats to the new mods!

Comment: congrats, now stop deleting my posts please :-)

Comment: Bravo to the other candidates who were so close!

Comment: OMG. My all three choices are winner. :D

Comment: Congrats guys. You will make great mods. Cheers :)

Comment: Congrats EdCottrell, josilber and MadaraUchiha! On your mark, get set, GO!

Comment: Congrats to new mods..:) but feeling sad for undo and deceeze.. And don't know why undo was not in one of them when he has highest votes :(

Comment: Congratulations guys! Glad to see two of my choices are up there!

Comment: We are looking for the reason of stepping down through answers like Bill did in the last election.

Comment: @VinodMadyalkar You're just near to Madara. Well done, think you got many fans..

Comment: Congrats guys! The people have chosen well. :)

Comment: @AvinashRaj - Lol. Yes, it was close. :)

Comment: @deceze don't loose your hope. I'm looking forward you to be on this page when the next election results came.

Comment: are their user links now 404 because they are mods?

Comment: @VinodMadyalkar You are so close mate. Better luck next time :)

Comment: @Omar - I don't think so. He is a good guy and people have faith in him. Don't go making comments about people. Keep them to yourself.

Comment: @VinodMadyalkar Well, I thought that you'll be busy with moderation by this time. Now deleting unrelated comments here :)

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ - Nope. Lol.

Comment: Congre88zzz all..  @JoshCrozie

Comment: Thanks casperOne, Gordon, and Jeremy. All the best wishes for you guys!

Comment: Shouldn't be any 404s, @dove - where are you seeing that?

Comment: I really wanted Undo to win :c

Comment: Thanks @DJDavid98 - next year! :)

Comment: @Shog9 when I clicked this morning (GMT) I got errors on each of the candidates, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/users/3093387/josilber. It gave me the error page.  After that comment I searched for josilber and got that error too.  Were their accounts being upgraded?

Comment: No, that shouldn't have happened, @dove. Post a bug report, please - with details on your browser & platform & a screenshot if possible.

Comment: 2 on 3, not bad.

Comment: @DJDavid98, yes i also wanted that undo will be mod as his answers were damn good..may be next year :)

Comment: @Avinash Raj: It's OK to hope (for lack of a better word) for an answer, but don't expect them to. They're not accountable to the community when they step down, and they most certainly are not obligated to reveal their personal lives to you.

Comment: Congrats EdCottrell, MadaraUchiha, and josilber! And thanks Thank you casperOne, Gordon, and Jeremy!

Comment: @Zanon Really? Given that [the nomination](http://stackoverflow.com/election/6#post-29528400) looked more like a joke than anything else, I was almost sure that this would happen.

Comment: Congratulations, Brand New mods! And @deceze, I'll just vote for you again next year.

Comment: These were the three that I voted for. I must be psychic...

Comment: Congratulations! Go Ed Cottrell!

Comment: @Shog9 logged that bug http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/311189/links-to-new-moderators-user-page-gave-error

Comment: Congrats EdCottrell, MadaraUchiha, and josilber. Cheers :D

Comment: Voted for you JOSILBER, Congratulations :-)

Comment: Congrats EdCottrell, MadaraUchiha, and josilber!

Comment: Many many congratulations to 3 stars!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Congrats to all 3 of you, use your sharingan wisely @MadaraUchiha :-)

Comment: Congratulations EdCottrell, MadaraUchiha, and josilber ...

Comment: Congrats to  EdCottrell, MadaraUchiha, and Josilber!

Comment: Kudos to all: elected moderators, runners up and electorate in general.  @EdCottrell i am your constituent.

Comment: Congratulations to the winners

Comment: Kudos and congratulations to ALL of the participants~~you are all winners for participating and for wanting to contribute more to SO.  To the 3 new moderators and the entire moderation team, especial thanks for your ongoing efforts to moderate SO.

Comment: A very hearful thanks to all the participants who took part in this election, as all the contestants here were good and deserving. But special congratulations to **josibler**, **Ed cottrell** and **Madara uchiha**. All the best. :)

Comment: Welcome aboard to the new mods! Godspeed :)

Comment: Congratulations to new moderators EdCottrell, MadaraUchiha, and josilber!

Comment: Congratulations EdCottrell, MadaraUchiha and Josilber.

Comment: I actually missed this election but from what I've seen, the new mods are already doing an excellent job. Congrats to them and thank you to the rest of the community for making such good picks.

Comment: Who downvotes a post like this?  That's not very classy.

Comment: Congratulations to the new moderators!
Keep doing good work :)

Comment: That's is why this is a great community. Also, this help to develop the world spreading knowledge and showing people that this is the future.

Comment: A Hearty congratulations to all the 3 Mods - **EdCottrell, MadaraUchiha, and josilber**. @EdCottrell, I was expecting you this time.. :)

Comment: @GuruprasadRao thanks! :)

Comment: Congrats for the new moderators EdCottrell, MadaraUchiha, and josilber!

Comment: Many congrats new mods! May you enjoy the experience and provide hope to flailing devs!

Comment: Many congrats to new moderatprs and also thanks to three moderators who are stepping down after giving so much to the community.

Comment: @Undo Congrats! You finally got in. All the best for you modship :)

Comment: @TheLostMind Congrats, Hopefully your inclusion will reduce some spam during the peak hours. :)

Comment: Thank you @BhargavRao and everyone who voted for me. I'll do my best not to disappoint!

Comment: @Undo You've got this! Congrats!

Comment: Congrats @Undo, get ready to handle my flags :-)

Answer (score 322):

With so many moderators coming and leaving, it may help to have a chart.

**Timeline of SO moderators**

[image: mod timeline]

Purple color indicates employment by Stack Overflow.

Sources:

- [LaTeX/tikz file](//gist.github.com/normalhuman/bfc442e569676b48952a) from a template by [Najib Idrissi](//math.stackexchange.com/users/10014/najib-idrissi) who created it for [Math.SE](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/19106).
- 2021 update by [Oleg Valter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11407695) ([repository](https://github.com/Oaphi/mods-tex)), forked from the original template.

Comment: Small flaw in the chart that unfortunately isn't really fixable with readily available data: some of those folks were called up some time between two elections on account of increased demand. It's a pretty minor point, though.

Comment: Also, look at that Adam Lear. What a slacker.

Comment: @AdamLear I did my best to dig out that info: you can see minitech and animuson starting a bit later.

Comment: nice chart! maybe add different color like reddish-purple to timeframe of those that are employees now, and so Adam won't seem like such slacker

Comment: Thanks @CRABOLO and Brad Koch, I updated accordingly.

Comment: I see a couple of users that were moderators for less than a year. Was there any reason for that? (I would expect moderators to last at least for a whole year)

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro Moderators are volunteers and are free to step down at any time; they don't owe us an explanation. Maybe something in their life has changed and they don't want to make it public.

Comment: I understand that. I didn't know if it had been their choice or SO's decision.  Has there been any case in which a moderator has been asked to step down?

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro: Yes, but SE has chosen not to make such cases public.

Answer (score 169):

Welp, that leaves me as the only remaining moderator from [the time I was elected](//stackoverflow.com/election/2) — the rest either stepped down or got <del>murdered</del> hired. I just finished serving my fourth year yesterday. It has been a pleasure working with the others who were elected alongside myself.

Congrats to all the new mods. Ed and I have spoken a couple of times in the Teachers' Lounge and I'm sure he'll feel right at home moderating SO, in spite of its sheer size. I've also spoken with josilber in the Tavern and fielded some of his flags personally and I can say with confidence that he knows what he's doing, and whenever in doubt he makes it a point to *ask* politely and learn.

That being said, Madara Uchiha was my first choice, not my third, and my reasons for that are twofold:

1. I didn't want to see him just miss the cut-off point yet again.
2. MRW he nominated after much persuasion (he wasn't originally going to for reason #1):

   [image]

OK, a third — he's one of the few users I'd say I'm on particularly close terms with in terms of the SO community. The first time we crossed paths, I think, he went by the name Truth, and I still remember his nondescript faceless-looking avatar (that, contrary to his current one, I'm not sure if it's a reference to anything).

We'd often cross paths due in most part to our common tags, and I've pretty much always had a good impression of him even since before *I* was elected, and it's only gotten better since he started out moderating Anime & Manga. He consistently demonstrates passion for Stack Exchange, leadership skills and, along with folks like Brad Larson and Bill the Lizard, exudes a level-headedness and professionalism I can't help but admire. They make me look like the poster child of the "angry moderator" trope by comparison.

And if you're a regular on [chat](//chat.stackoverflow.com), I'm sure you can vouch for him as well. Not very many of the veteran moderators use chat much, let alone moderate it effectively. Madara's different. He knows the people, the culture. He *knows* what he's doing.

And that's why I've been pinning my hopes on him ascending to modhood on Stack Overflow. It's finally happened, and I couldn't be more thrilled to have him on board.

Thanks to those stepping down for their contributions not only to the moderation team, but the site as a whole. I look forward to working with my new colleagues/comrades.

Comment: YOU'RE MY BOY MADARA!

Comment: @Mad time to update your *about me*!

Comment: Madara sensei please start dropping meteors on the mortals; show no mercy !

Comment: Well, soon enough we will be all under the Infinite Tsukuyomi @MadaraUchiha, well played....

Comment: Pretty sure this will be full of more Madara memes. Best of luck to to all the moderators. Hope to see @MadaraUchiha live up to his legendary name. Contrary to the anime Stackoverflow will be the place where Madara leads his clan (entire Konoha).

Comment: You just can't say no to a such a badass as Madara...

Comment: Thanks for the kind words BoltClock -- looking forward to moderating with you!

Comment: One cannot simply turn down Madara...

Comment: Just waiting for Naruto to come then we'll have real competition with Madara :P

Comment: he has us all under some massive godlike illusion spell to make us think he's the best huh ? well, maybe he is after all. I'm no exception to that, voted for him as first choice too - and although I hardly know him my impression of the guy is quite close to this. Go figure :)

Comment: @berserk You were saying something... ? ;)

Comment: Please, Naruto can't match up to me even with Sasuke on his side.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha Ahem Ahem!!

Answer (score 55):

I would like to say congratulations to the three new moderators, but I also want to say thanks to all those candidates who didn't win. even though you didn't make it, it was great to see you all reaching for the goal.

Comment: Indeed.  It's great to see so much talent competing for stewardship of the community here.

Answer (score 13):

To the new moderators, congratulations! I wish you all and the whole community the best. I started very late to participate in Stack Overflow and my goal is to one day nominate in the elections and become someone who can help the others. But as they say: *It's never too late*, right? I still have much to learn.

Congratulations again. BTW, I voted for `Ed` and `Madara`. So it means I won as well. Right? :D

Comment: Keep in mind that you don't need to be a moderator to help others. Answer questions, help out with reviews etc ;-)

Comment: @Cerbrus  True that. That's what I'm trying to do everyday :)

Comment: @Peter Mortensen Don't forget to add the "too" to "It's never late." :-)

Comment: @HeadCode I've done it myself. Thanks :P

Answer (score 8):

A big congratulations to the newly elected moderators!

This election holds special values for me. I used to be a blind voter till this election, voting just by reading the post in the election poll. But in this election, I followed the discussion and voted accordingly. I read your answers to the questions. This motivated me enough to take part in meta discussions actively.

I want to thank Stack Overflow for holding such a great democratic election and to all the participants. I am sure the winners will do good work.

Comment: Which specific answers to which questions swung it for you? I was too busy to take a look this election.

Comment: Be careful, getting involved on Meta is a trap!

Answer (score 6):

Looking at votes and how they were transferred, there are two **clear** winners, with two **clear** runner ups.

We all know that the work load for moderators is very high, therefore why not appoint 4 new moderators?

Comment: Probably because they announced it as a three-seat election and didn't want to change midstream. But with three resignations, it's quite likely SE will call up one or two of the runners-up before the next election.

Comment: @MichaelMyers: I assumed the election was called only *because* of those three resignations, but you might well be right.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, I would like to say that you are the true winners and deserving person of the great democratic election, as you are elected by the users who have voted for you to see you as a moderator!

Second, I also would like to say thanks to [all other candidates](https://stackoverflow.com/election/7) who were standing in the election 2015, especially feeling very sad for [Deceze](https://stackoverflow.com/users/476/deceze).

At last, a big big congratulations to newly elected our three moderators - [Josilber](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3093387/josilber),
[Ed-cottrell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2057919/ed-cottrell) and 
[Madara-Uchiha](https://stackoverflow.com/users/871050/madara-uchiha). I am damn sure you guys will put your best efforts to make us feel lucky!

This was the first time I voted in a Stack Overflow election; let's have a dream to be a moderator in future.

Answer (score 2):

Wow thats kinda motivates me to work more hard and then become moderator like you guys. A very big congratulations Josilber, Ed-cottrell and Madara-Uchiha.

Answer (score -1):

I would like to extend my warm wishes to all the selected moderators. :). Hope you will do the job to the best of your abilities. Again congratulations.

A big thanks to all the members who participated in all the phases of the election and made it successful.

Answer (score -1):

Congratulation to all elected moderators,hope to see improvement in StackOverflow through your impact and action towards her progress.Also enjoy the work of all moderator in this community ,they make you do things the proper way.Kudos to you all.

Answer (score -2):

Congratulations, all the moderators and all the people who won or not, the precious and important thing is that they gave their golden time from busy schedule and sharing the solutions and knowledge with the world. Thank you all, thank you so much. Thank you stackoverflow.