# Asking why someone else’s answer was deleted

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers, specific-answer

[This answer to *Change type of a column with numbers from varchar to int*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/577712/change-type-of-a-column-with-numbers-from-varchar-to-int/4076527#4076527) was deleted a few years before I answered the same question (before I had enough reputation points to see deleted posts), and I’m curious if it’s possible to find out why it was deleted. It looks like a good answer to me.

Comment: Someone named "casperOne" deleted it, and since he deleted it without help, I'm assuming that he had mod powers at that time.

Comment: Maybe it was deleted because it starts with a question and that make it look that a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: casperOne is [still active](https://stackoverflow.com/users/50776/casperone) and so you can ping him on any one of his questions, answers, or edits, and point him to this question. Then again, it was six and a half years ago.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're probably not going to find out *why* it was deleted in all reality.  casperOne likely did so [when following moderator protocol](https://stackoverflow.com/election/2) back in '11 (and the reason they're not a mod *now* is because they [stepped down in '15](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/311045/1079354)).

*If* you think it's  a reasonable answer, you could cast an undelete vote on it instead.  I don't agree with it - I'm not seeing much of an actual answer there, more like a "try this" style response - but I have other votes to communicate quality.